# Simplify numerous if, elseifs in java

Tags: java, if-statement, lambda

I am here to seek help w.rt. simplifying if-elseif statements in java. Here's my code below, which has numerous if, elseifs. Is it possible to simplify the below code using java lambda features? Can I reduce if, elseif statements in my method? Can we use Java 8 filter functionality here?

```
public ReturnsRetailerConfigPromotionResponse promoteRetailerConfig(
        ReturnsRetailerConfigPromotionRequest returnsRetailerConfigPromotionRequest,
        String configType) {
        try{
            if(isTenantConfigPromotion){
                tenantDetails = returnsGenericUtils.getTenantConfig(sourceRetailerName, sourceHubLoginResponse);
            }
            else if(isTrackConfigPromotion){
                returnsGenericUtils.downloadTrackConfig(sourceRetailerName, sourceHubcookies);
            }
            else if(isReturnRulesPromotion){
                returnsGenericUtils.downloadReturnRules(sourceRetailerName, sourceHubcookies);
            }
            else if(isReturnReasonsPromotion){
                returnsGenericUtils.downloadReturnReasons(sourceRetailerName, sourceHubcookies);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            return new ReturnsRetailerConfigPromotionResponse(...);
        }
}
```

Comment: that depends on the logic, but it's likely not, since your ifs are based on separate booleans (or so it seems). This is, however, quite compact as code, why try to "simplify" what's already quite simple?

Comment: Thank you for your response @Stultuske! I have put in here only few if,elseif statements here. In-fact there are many more in it. So, was just exploring a way, if I can simplify in some way.

Comment: even if it is possible, it looks to me like you would just make the code much more complex

Comment: Firstly, you might what to learn what [Functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) is, and spend a bit of your time familiarizing with functional programming features (which you refer to as Java 8 lambdas). Oracle provides a fairly good [*tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) for zero cost, just read through it, you'll find all the information that you need to start with lambdas and stream.

Comment: do the `if` and `else` involve dozen of criteria? if not, you might be [wasting your time](https://xkcd.com/1319/)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I would remove redundant "else if" statements, if the only 'true' case is possible, like this:

```
            if(isTenantConfigPromotion){
                tenantDetails = returnsGenericUtils.getTenantConfig(sourceRetailerName, sourceHubLoginResponse);
            }
            if(isTrackConfigPromotion){
                returnsGenericUtils.downloadTrackConfig(sourceRetailerName, sourceHubcookies);
            }
            if(isReturnRulesPromotion){
                returnsGenericUtils.downloadReturnRules(sourceRetailerName, sourceHubcookies);
            }
            if(isReturnReasonsPromotion){
                returnsGenericUtils.downloadReturnReasons(sourceRetailerName, sourceHubcookies);
            }
```

And then I would think about moving the block somewhere else, cause` it looks like a side effect:

```
if(isTenantConfigPromotion){
  tenantDetails = ..
}
```

If you realy want to use lambdas here, than you can try to transform boolean conditions into text values, and make something like:

```
private static final Map<String, BiConsumer<Object, Object>> DOWNLOADERS_MAPPING = Map.of(
            "isTrackConfigPromotion", returnsGenericUtils::getTenantConfig,
            "isReturnRulesPromotion", returnsGenericUtils::downloadReturnRules,
            "isReturnReasonsPromotion", returnsGenericUtils::downloadReturnReasons
    );

public ReturnsRetailerConfigPromotionResponse promoteRetailerConfig(
            ReturnsRetailerConfigPromotionRequest returnsRetailerConfigPromotionRequest,
            String configType,
            Set<String> conditions
    ) {
        try {
            conditions.forEach(condition -> {
                DOWNLOADERS_MAPPING.getOrDefault(condition, returnsGenericUtils::doNothing).accept(sourceRetailerName, sourceHubcookies);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            return new ReturnsRetailerConfigPromotionResponse(...);
        }
    }
```

than it's gonna be easier to extend the method if you get more conditions.

Comment: removing the else might have serious consequences if the conditions aren't exclusive, though

Comment: as I said,  "if the only 'true' case is possible"